# An error in CVXR occurring with large datasets

Tags: r, optimization, cvx

I have been trying to fit a thin-plate spline to a brain scan dataset using the popular `CVXR` package in `R`, but unfortunately the main function of that package returns an error I have been unable to decipher. Here is the example I've been working on.

```
require(gamair)
require(CVXR)
require(npreg)
data(brain)
x = brain[, c(1, 2)]
x <- as.matrix(x)
z = brain$medFPQ
z <- as.vector(z)

m = 2
b.tp <- basis.tps(x, knots = x, m = m, rk = TRUE, intercept = TRUE)
pen.tp <- penalty.tps(x, m = m, rk = TRUE)
mstar <- choose(m+dim(x)[2]-1, dim(x)[2])
pen.tp <- rbind(matrix(0, ncol = dim(pen.tp)[2]+mstar, nrow = mstar), cbind( matrix(0, nrow = dim(pen.tp)[1], ncol = mstar ), pen.tp ) )
theta <- Variable(dim(b.tp)[2])
obj <- sum((z-b.tp%*%theta)^2) + 1e-01*quad_form(theta, pen.tp)
prob <- Problem(Minimize(obj))
result <- solve(prob, solver = "SCS")
```

And the error is

```
Error in (function (cl, name, valueClass)  : 
  assignment of an object of class “complex” is not valid for @‘eigvals’ in an object of class “Constant”; is(value, "numeric") is not TRUE
```

I have been wondering what causes this, as I have not found any relevant information. I have, however, noticed that this error is much less likely to appear with smaller datasets. For example, if we use only a couple of hundred randomly sampled observations out of the 1567 available ones.

If anyone has additional information on how to resolve this problem, could I please ask for their help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the error (R 4.2.0 on GNU/Linux). But to venture a wild guess: apparently a complex value was computed, which would for instance happen when a square-root is computed from a negative number. Such a negative number might be only "numeric noise" (i.e. caused by rounding error and actually zero). Such a close-to-zero negative number might be the result of a computation that required a full-rank matrix, but did receive a rank-deficient matrix.

My session info:

```
sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 21.10

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-openmp/libblas.so.3
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas-openmp/libopenblasp-r0.3.13.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] CVXR_1.0-10  npreg_1.0-8  gamair_1.0-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3     lattice_0.20-45  codetools_0.2-18 gmp_0.6-5       
 [5] slam_0.1-50      grid_4.2.0       R6_2.5.1         Rmpfr_0.8-7     
 [9] Matrix_1.4-1     tools_4.2.0      bit64_4.0.5      bit_4.0.4       
[13] compiler_4.2.0   scs_3.0-0        cccp_0.2-7       Rglpk_0.6-4
```

Comment: Do you mean that the code runs without error on your machine?

Comment: Yes, the code runs. I have added my session info.

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why it runs on your machine and not on mine. I am also using the latest version of R. I suspect the error is due to the penalty matrix pen.tp being ill-conditioned.

Answer (score 1):

To my eye, I see nothing stochastic in your problem, so the results should exactly be what @JohnK got. I can also confirm that `CVXR` solves this problem. Any reason you're using `SCS` as the solver? For the default solver (`OSQP`) is three times as fast, and returns an optimal status, which, btw, one should always check!

```
> system.time(result <- solve(prob))
   user  system elapsed 
 49.118  24.082  42.783 
> cat(sprintf("Results---solver: %s, status: %s, value: %f\n", result$solver, result$status, result$value))
Results---solver: OSQP, status: optimal, value: 1172.806162
> system.time(result <- solve(prob, solver = "SCS"))
   user  system elapsed 
130.451  26.029 122.103 
> cat(sprintf("Results---solver: %s, status: %s, value: %f\n", result$solver, result$status, result$value))
Results---solver: SCS, status: optimal_inaccurate, value: 1172.570113
```

And here is my session:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin21.3.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.4

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.20/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.20.dylib
LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.0/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] npreg_1.0-8  CVXR_1.0-10  gamair_1.0-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3     bit_4.0.4        lattice_0.20-45  R6_2.5.1        
 [5] tools_4.2.0      grid_4.2.0       osqp_0.6.0.5     scs_3.0-0       
 [9] bit64_4.0.5      assertthat_0.2.1 cccp_0.2-7       Matrix_1.4-1    
[13] gmp_0.6-5        Rglpk_0.6-4      codetools_0.2-18 slam_0.1-50     
[17] Rcplex_0.3-5     gurobi_9.5-1     compiler_4.2.0   Rmpfr_0.8-7     
[21] rcbc_0.1.0.9001  Rmosek_9.3.2    
>
```